# SharePoint CAML View Elements index

Tags: sharepoint, element, caml

I find it hard to find available elements I can use when creating Views. Also on MSDN they are paginated over 3 pages.

Would be nice if this could be improved with examples like what can we do with these properties, because MS documentation does not provide that.

So here they are:

### [Aggregations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms468626.aspx)

### [Batch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms437562.aspx)

### [Case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms443262.aspx)

### [Column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms411957.aspx)

### [Column2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms448772.aspx)

### [ContentTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543547.aspx)

### [Counter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460915.aspx)

### [CurrentRights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979585.aspx)

### [Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms412769.aspx)

### [Else](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms475477.aspx)

### [Expr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms433520.aspx)

### [Expr1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms465983.aspx)

### [Expr2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms457125.aspx)

### [Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms442120.aspx)

### [FieldPrefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms441410.aspx)

### [FieldProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms470185.aspx)

### [FieldRef](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms436424.aspx)

### [Fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms432435.aspx)

### [FieldSortParams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms470896.aspx)

### [FieldSwitch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms412771.aspx)

### [FilterLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms442059.aspx)

### [ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms474335.aspx)

### [GetFileExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms413702.aspx)

### [GetVar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms429081.aspx)

### [GroupByFooter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms448750.aspx)

### [GroupByHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms436781.aspx)

### [HTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms440498.aspx)

### [HttpHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464622.aspx)

### [HttpPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms457129.aspx)

### [HttpVDir](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415537.aspx)

### [ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms432368.aspx)

### [Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms439477.aspx)

### [IfEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms454493.aspx)

### [IfHasRights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms452717.aspx)

### [IfNeg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms439119.aspx)

### [IfNew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms462807.aspx)

### [IfSubString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms473918.aspx)

### [Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535061.aspx)

### [Joins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535493.aspx)

### [Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms451408.aspx)

### [Limit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms440854.aspx)

### [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms466107.aspx)

### [ListProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms466436.aspx)

### [ListUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979700.aspx)

### [ListUrlDir](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms474877.aspx)

### [LookupColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms414932.aspx)

### [MapToAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms458494.aspx)

### [MapToControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms475673.aspx)

### [MapToIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms412237.aspx)

### [MeetingProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms452692.aspx)

Known selectable properties

- `<MeetingProperty Select="InstanceID" />` returns 20100908
- `<MeetingProperty Select="MeetingCount" />`
- `<MeetingProperty Select="StartTimeUTC" />` returns 20100908T073000Z

### [Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms459050.aspx)

### [More](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979749.aspx)

### [PageUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms439653.aspx)

### [ProjectProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415143.aspx)

### [ProjectedFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535502.aspx)

### [Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms459173.aspx)

### [RightsChoices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms461362.aspx)

### [RightsGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms435946.aspx)

### [ScriptQuote](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms481133.aspx)

### [SelectionOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms413156.aspx)

### [ServerProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms413099.aspx)

### [SetList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms475910.aspx)

### [SetVar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms477697.aspx)

### [Switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms465598.aspx)

### [Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979502.aspx)

### [Then](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979502.aspx)

### [ThreadStamp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms477346.aspx)

### [URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms459906.aspx)

### [UrlBaseName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms413130.aspx)

### [UrlDirName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms469877.aspx)

### [UserID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms412517.aspx)

### [WebQueryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms474379.aspx)

Reference: View Schema Elements [A-F](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979500.aspx) [G-L](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979703.aspx) [M-Z](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa978513.aspx)